# Why doesn't the coefficient of linear expansion decrease with increase in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

If temperature is increased, then the change in temperature also increases. If the change in temperature increases, the coefficient of linear expansion should also increase according to the formula 
(change in length/length*change in temperature)
But why isn't it so?

Comment: It does change. But since the change in length is very small compared to length we assume the length to be constant while calculating the coefficient of linear expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to say that since $$\alpha = \frac{\Delta l}{l_0 \Delta T},$$ then with change in temperature, the constant $\alpha$ should also change.

However, for small changes in temperature, the ratio $\frac {\Delta l}{\Delta T}$ remains fairly constant, such that $\alpha$ remains constant.

Comment: In any event, as pointed out by @SR810, the coefficient of linear expansion does change with temperature (over broader regions of temperature).

Comment: Of course, and that's why I wrote `for small changes in temperature`.